# Mirth 3.11.0 Upgrade on Linux Without GUI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, upgrade, mirth

My mirth is running on an AWS EC2 instance.  I want to upgrade the version of Mirth Connect running there. I am currently using 3.8.0, which I want to upgrade to version 3.11. However, I haven't found any good instructions or scripts for performing the upgrade that does not involve GUI tools. Does anyone know where I can find such a script or instructions?

Answer (score 0):

In place upgrades are not safe, given enhancements within Mirth Connect itself and JRE. Many changes might have happened across versions 3.9 and 3.10. I suggest getting the appropriate tar.gz file version from the NextGen website then installing version 3.11.0 as a second instance while assigning different HTTP and HTTPS ports. You can then export channels in version 3.8 and do incremental imports to version 3.11.0 while you monitor closely. The command line interface documentation [here](https://forums.mirthproject.io/forum/mirth-connect/support/7582-mirth-cli-documentation) offers an easier way to handle channel exports and imports.